# Metro/Windows8 compile error: LoadState() => no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to work through this Metro "Hello World" on MSVS 11 Beta, with the Windows 8 Community Preview:

[Create Your First Metro Style App using C# or VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx)

The tutorial asks you to create some "template" pages.  For example:

```
public sealed partial class SplitPage : WindowsBlogReader.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
   ...
```

The tutorial also asks you to override the LoadState() method for some of these pages:

```
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        // TODO: Assign a bindable group to this.DefaultViewModel["Group"]
        // TODO: Assign a collection of bindable items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]
        FeedData feedData = navigationParameter as FeedData;        
        if (feedData != null)
        {
            this.DefaultViewModel["Feed"] = feedData;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = feedData.Items;
        }
        ...
```

The problem is that this dies with a nasty compile error:

```
LoadState(object,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>): no suitable method found to override.
```

There is no "Page state management" region and no default "LoadState()" method in the auto-generated code for the template (SplitPage.xaml.cs); the tutorial says there *should* be.

Q: Is LoadState() now deprecated in newer versions of the Metro SDK?

Q: Do I need to do something "magic" in a .xaml file to make this work?

Q: What the heck is going on here?

Thank you very much in advance, if anybody has any suggestions!
tutorial also asks you to override the LoadState() method for some of these pages:

Comment: Your base class `LayoutAwarePage` contains `LoadState`, so `protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)` will work. I however stumbled in here because my `LoadState(...)` doesn't execute. :/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem and then later I used same code in method OnNavigatedTo() of SplitPage.xaml.cs as given below and it just worked fine.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The
    /// Parameter property provides the group to be displayed.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Assign a bindable group to this.DefaultViewModel["Group"]
        // TODO: Assign a collection of bindable items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]
        FeedData feedData = e.Parameter  as FeedData;
        if (feedData != null)
        {
            this.DefaultViewModel["Feed"] = feedData;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = feedData.Items;
        }


        // Select the first item automatically unless logical page navigation is
        // being used (see the logical page navigation #region below.)
        if (!this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation()) this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }
```

One minor change I did is that I used e.Parameter instead of navigationParameter .

Answer (score 0):

Did you port an old Metro app and forgot to update the LayOutAware page in the Common folder ?